# Compare types in Javascript

Tags: javascript, comparison, typeof

I saw in Crockford's Book *Javascript: The Good Parts* that he does typeof comparison like this:

```
return typeof a < typeof b ? -1 : 1;
```

I made my own tests and I think this is the "ordering" of the different types:

> function < number < object or array < string < undefined

Is this how JS actually does the comparison?

Comment: Why would you need to test if a type is "less than" another? What does that even mean? Besides `typeof()` returns a string, so its really a [lexographic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexicographical_order) comparison.

Comment: @Chad: Probably sorting values in an Array by type using `Array.prototype.sort`. [Here's an example](http://jsfiddle.net/6SSZP/)

Comment: @amnotiam Like I said its not going to sort based on some type precedence though, it will sort lexicographically on the type string.

Comment: @Chad: I guess I should have said "grouping by type via sorting by typeof" instead of mere sorting. I haven't read *The Good Parts* (and have no plan to) so I don't know what the context is.

Comment: @amnotiam I agree I think the context of this statement makes all the difference. Defining a grouping sort is the only thing I can think of for this...

Comment: @Chad Crockford uses the comparison in a function that sorts an array of simple values.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `typeof` operator returns a string. String are compared by its numeric value.

So, the `<` comparison order would be:

```
type       charCode ("tfnosux".charCodeAt(i))   Example
boolean     98                                   true
function   102                                   Date
number     110                                   123
object     111                                   []
string     115                                   ""
undefined  117                                   undefined
xml        120                                   <x></x>
```

*`tfnosux` are the first characters of the types*. The [`charCodeAt`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/charCodeAt) method returns the numeric charCode of a character in JavaScript.

I have added an example of each type at the previous block. Most JavaScript developers know about the first types. The final type, `xml`, is less commonly known, and can be obtained by using `typeof` on  [EX4](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ECMAScript_for_XML).

**Demo of `typeof`: http://jsfiddle.net/9G9zt/1/**

Comment: Your list seems slightly off -- shouldn't `O` come before `S`?

Comment: @bobbymcr I noticed when calculating the numeric charcode values. It has been corrected ;)

Comment: What's an example of something of xml data type?

Comment: @qwertymk I've constructed an example. Have a look at the The updated answer.

Comment: @Chad Wrong, the `typeof xmlDocument` is also returns object. Have a look at the updated answer for the true explanation + demo.

Comment: @RobW my mistake, comment removed.

Comment: I'm getting an error in Chrome's ropl when I type `<x>xmltest</x>` ->
`SyntaxError: Unexpected token <`

Comment: @qwertymk Because EX4 is not supported (yet) by V8, Chrome's JavaScript engine. See also: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ECMAScript_for_XML#Browser_support

Comment: @RobW: Firefox too: `>>> <x></x>
TypeError: can't wrap XML objects
[Break On This Error] with(_FirebugCommandLine){ `

Comment: `typeof(<x></x>)` returns "xml" in firebug console, `<x></x>` OR `var x = <x></x>` returns the error you describe.

Answer (score 2):

It is not importance.  `typeof` returns a string, and the comparison operators work for strings, by performing a "a simple lexicographic ordering on sequences of code point value values".

Basically, if one string starts with the other, then that is the greater of the two, otherwise the first character position that differs between the two is compared.

See section 11.8.5 of the [spec](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST-ARCH/ECMA-262,%203rd%20edition,%20December%201999.pdf)